# How to add toUpperCase function in Z3?

Tags: z3, smt

I have tried the following code in Z3. But Z3 said model is not available.

```
(declare-const s String)
(declare-fun toUppercase (String) (String))

(assert (= (str.len s) (str.len (toUppercase s))))
(assert (forall ((i Int) (x String))
  (let ((a!1 (and (not (= (str.at x i) "a"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "b"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "c"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "d"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "e"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "f"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "g"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "h"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "i"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "j"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "k"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "l"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "m"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "n"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "o"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "p"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "q"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "r"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "s"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "t"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "u"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "v"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "w"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "x"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "y"))
                  (not (= (str.at x i) "z"))
                  (= (str.at x i) (str.at (toUppercase x) i)))))
  (let ((a!2 (or (and (= (str.at x i) "a") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "A"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "b") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "B"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "c") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "C"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "d") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "D"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "e") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "E"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "f") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "F"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "g") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "G"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "h") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "H"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "i") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "I"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "j") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "J"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "k") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "K"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "l") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "L"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "m") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "M"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "n") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "N"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "o") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "O"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "p") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "P"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "q") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "Q"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "r") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "R"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "s") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "S"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "t") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "T"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "u") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "U"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "v") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "V"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "w") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "W"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "x") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "X"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "y") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "Y"))
                 (and (= (str.at x i) "z") (= (str.at (toUppercase x) i) "Z"))
                 a!1)))
    (=> (and (>= i 0) (< i (str.len x))) a!2)))))
(assert (str.prefixof "hE" s))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I was thinking maybe I could implement a replaceAll function to replace all lower-case characters with upper-case characters.  But I cannot get the replaceAll function work as well.

This is my first try using define-fun-rec:

```
(set-option :smt.mbqi true)
(define-fun-rec replaceAll ((x!1 String) (x!2 String) (x!3 String)) (String)
  (let ((I (str.indexof x!1 x!2) )) 
    (if (= I -1) x!1
      (replaceAll (str.replace x!1 x!2 x!3) x!2 x!3)
    )
  )
)
(declare-const a String)
(simplify (replaceAll "aba" "a" "A"))
(assert (= (replaceAll a "a" "A") "Ab"))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

This is my 2nd try using conditional macros:

```
(declare-fun replaceAll (String String String String) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x!1 String) (x!2 String) (x!3 String) (x!4 String)) 
                (=> (= -1 (str.indexof x!1 x!2)) (replaceAll x!1 x!2 x!3 x!4))))
(assert (forall ((S String) (r String) (T String) (R String)) 
                (=>
                  (>= (str.indexof S r) 0)
                  (exists ((U String) (M String) (S1 String) (R1 String))
                    (and (= S (str.++ U M S1))
                         (= R (str.++ U T R1))
                         (= M r)
                         (= (str.len U) (str.indexof S r))
                         (replaceAll S1 r T R1))
                    )
                  ))) 

(declare-const a String)
(assert (= a "ab"))
(assert (replaceAll a "a" "A" "Ab") )

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I would appreciate any guidance you could offer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be out of scope of what the String procedure can handle with respect to how it saturates constraints.
You are basically describing a transducer. There is currently no support for reasoning about transducers other than instantiating axioms about them. 
There are tools that handle transducers natively and constraint solving around them. For example, the Bek/Bex tools (http://rise4fun.com/bex, http://rise4fun.com/bek) and the automata toolkit (http://research.microsoft.com/~margus, https://github.com/AutomataDotNet/Automata).